# Spring MVC -- flash attributes not displaying in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf, message, flash-message

I've confirmed that i'm packing the `RedirectAttributes` with a `BusinessAuth` object with non-empty strings. What am I doing wrong?

**AdminController**:

```
@RequestMapping(path = BASE_URI + "/auth/business")
public String generateBusinessKeys(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    String keyBusiness = ControllerUtil.getNewAuthKey();
    String keyMobile = ControllerUtil.getNewAuthKey();
    BusinessAuth auth = new BusinessAuth(keyBusiness, keyMobile);
    businessAuthService.save(auth);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("businessAuth", auth);

    return "/admin/home";
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<p th:if="${businessAuth} != null" th:text="admin: "></p>
<p th:if="${businessAuth} != null" th:text="${businessAuth.keyAdmin}"></p> <br />
<p th:if="${businessAuth} != null" th:text="mobile: "></p> <br />
<p th:if="${businessAuth} != null" th:text="${businessAuth.keyMobile}"></p> <br />
```

**BusinessAuth**:

```
@Entity
public class BusinessAuth extends BaseEntity {

private String keyMobile;
private String keyAdmin;

public BusinessAuth() {}

public BusinessAuth(String keyMobile, String keyAdmin) {
    this.keyMobile = keyMobile;
    this.keyAdmin = keyAdmin;
}

public String getKeyMobile() {
    return keyMobile;
}

public String getKeyAdmin() {
    return keyAdmin;
}
```

}

Comment: flash attributes are to be used after a redirect, however you aren't redirecting only forwarding. Thus the variables will never be added to the the model. Instead just add them to the model or redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the attribute on a `ModelMap` did the trick.